# Show field only once after created Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to create an implementation of API Keys for my API, so the Externals can request an API Key and they will have access to my resources. Right now I'm using the Django admin to show and create these API Keys

```
class External(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

    is_enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    revenue_percentage = models.FloatField()

    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ApiToken(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

    external = models.ForeignKey(External, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    token_hash = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:  # In order to know if it's being created
            api_key = get_random_string(length=32)

            concat = f'{self.id}:{api_key}'
            key_bytes = concat.encode('ascii')
            base = base64.b64encode(key_bytes)
            token = base.decode('ascii')
            self.token = token
            self.token_hash = make_password(api_key)

        super(ApiToken, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and this is the admin

```
class ApiTokenAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ApiToken
    extra = 0
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'token', 'created')
    readonly_fields = ('created', 'token')
    exclude = ('id',)


class ExternalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('id', 'name',)
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'revenue_percentage', 'is_enabled',)
    list_filter = ('is_enabled',)
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'is_enabled', 'revenue_percentage')
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'created')

    inlines = [ApiTokenAdmin]


admin.site.register(External, ExternalAdmin)
```

As you see I'm storing the token that I want to share

```
self.token = token
```

The thing is I don't want to store that token in the database, I just want to calculate and show it once after a new API Key is created then the Admin can copy and share it with the Externals.

Is there a way to do this, I tried to override the `save_model` and `save_formset` but they just don't return the new object so I cannot set the value after the `save` method is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use django signals to remove the value from the database immediatly after the object is created.I guess pre_save or post_save can do the thing